# Return Table with Stored Procedure in PostgreSql?

Tags: postgresql, function, stored-procedures, return, output-parameter

How can I return table in Stored Procedure ? I can do it in function but I have inout parameters.So I can not create in function. What can I do this case ?

Iguess,It should be like for function :

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION public."test" (INOUT "x" integer, INOUT "y" text)

RETURNS TABLE  (
"id" integer,
"filesize" character varying(36)
)
AS $$
 BEGIN
RETURN QUERY
SELECT * FROM    public."tbl_employees" ;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use a procedure when you don't want to return data. Use a function when you do.

Comment: Stored procedures aren't meant to return anything. Your function is the best way to do that in Postgres

Comment: So I can not use a inout parameter